# Coherent Mathematical curriculum for someone with a CS degree

Tags: reference-request, self-learning

I recently finished my CS degree, And want to specialize in the "AI" field, the typical academic route (Master degree -> PHD -> More research) is my goal. But I feel like my mathematical background is not that "mature" **yet** (I'm aware that learning will never stops).

Thus, I'm looking for a coherent (no circular dependencies as I faced before) mathematical curriculum, **perhaps a bottom-up approach?** (for example : start with X then Y, Then choose either W or Z,... that kind of stuff)

I don't want to be scratching the surface again, nor switching from a resource to another. Up untilthis date, all my queries were inconclusive. All what I found is some "goal-oriented" stuff (usually something like do linear algebra, or calculus, or probability and statistics, etc) which has no logical form | sequence.

Is it a mixture of information overload and little guidance which causes this?
Or is it my initial approach of wanting to learn mathematics in a **"low"** level way ?

Comment: I am not sure this is OT here. More-over, it is too vague. You could try in Math Educators SE or Academia SE.

Answer (score 1):

For AI, you must study probability and statistics, information theory, and linear algebra.  Once you get into a specific domain (speech & language, vision, planning, etc.), then the required mathematics will become obvious from the papers you read and the guidance from your dissertation advisor.